# Calling a Python function on each entry of a text file

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I'm trying to find regex matches to each entry of a text file in order to structure the data better.

Keeps returning "No match" but if I call the function manually on the entry, it works.

```
import re

# The patterns
r1 = re.compile('.*full.*time.*', flags = re.IGNORECASE)
r2 = re.compile('.*contingent.*', flags = re.IGNORECASE)
r3 = re.compile('.*intern', flags = re.IGNORECASE)

def doSomething1():
    print ("Full Time")

def doSomething2():
    print("Contract")

def doSomething3():
    print("Internship")

def default():
    print ("No match")

def match(r, s):
    mo = re.match(r, s)
    try:
        return mo.group()
    except AttributeError:
        return None

def delegate(s):
    try:
        action = {
            match(r1, s): doSomething1,
            match(r2, s): doSomething2,
            match(r3, s): doSomething3
        }[s]()
        return action
    except KeyError:
        return default()

with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for job in data:
      delegate(job)
```

This is the data.txt:

```
Full Time Remote
Contingent
Intern
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set flags as `flags = re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL`, then the three lines will all match.

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), If the `DOTALL` flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

But your design of `delegate` is a little bad. You'd better tell us what you really/finally want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match `Full Time Remote` but it is matching `Full Time Remote\n`. In fact, each line in the file is followed by a newline character, so you won't get any matches  since `.` matches any character except a newline by default. You can handle it by `re.DOTALL` flag as Lei Yang said or having `s.strip()` to remove newline.

However, I think string method is enough to do the task.

```
def delegate(s):
    # ignore case by lower() and remove newline by strip()
    s = s.lower().strip("\n")
    # check index by find() to ensure "full" before "time"
    if "full" in s and s.find("full") < s.find("time"):
        print("Full Time")
    elif "contingent" in s:
        print("Contract")
    # last 6 characters are "intern"
    elif s[-6:] == "intern":
        print("Intern")
    else:
        print("No match")

with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for job in data:
        delegate(job)
```

With `data.txt` as:

```
Full Time Remote
Time Remote Full
Contingent
Intern
Intern 123
```

Result:

```
Full Time
No match
Contract
Intern
No match
```